Docker not copying contents to desired directory
Please be kind, I am new to Docker but have spent many hours trying to resolve this. I am simply trying to download latest nodejs and build the docker container, that is all.
Here is the Dockerfile:
# Use the official Node.js image from Docker Hub
FROM node:latest

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /usr/jim/dockerwork

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json from the /usr/jim/docker-app directory
COPY /usr/jim/docker-app/package*.json ./

# Install the dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application files from /usr/jim/docker-app into the container
COPY /usr/jim/docker-app .

# Expose port 8080 to the outside world
EXPOSE 8080

# Start the application
CMD ["npm", "start"] 

When I run docker build -t I get this issue:
On step 3 COPY I get "no source files were specified"
What am I doing wrong? The directory I wrote the Dockerfile and contains my index.js is the dockerwork folder, but the application is in the docker-app folder.

The left-hand side of COPY is relative to the build context directory, usually the directory containing the Dockerfile (and more specifically the . argument to docker build).  You cannot use an absolute path there.

I seem to have resolved that but step 4 throws:
npm error code ENOENT
npm error syscall open
npm error path /usr/jim/dockerwork/package.json
npm error errno -2
npm error enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/jim/dockerwork/package.json'
npm error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm error enoent
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-10-09T16_41_22_327Z-debug-0.log```

Updated dockerfile:
`FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /home/jim/dockerwork
COPY . /home/jim/Docker-App
RUN npm install
COPY /home/jim/Docker-App .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "start"]`
failing at 4 with package.json not found, but it is there..

You can also use . on the right-hand side of COPY, where it will refer to the current WORKDIR; so COPY ./ ./ would be very typical.

For line 3? Even if I am copying from WORKDIR (current location) to a different diirectroy?

I did that and it seemed to pass but then step 5 failed. file not found in build context?
